# Trying to get data with PHP from XML that uses only str

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have been trying to figure it out for hours. Im trying to get data out of XMl which uses only str attributes. Here is a example XMl im trying to use.

```
 <doc>
 <str name="author">timothy</str>
<str name="author_s">timothy</str>
<str name="title">French Gov't Runs Vast Electronic Spying Operation of Its Own</str>
<arr name="category">
  <str>communications</str>
</arr>
<str name="slash-section">yro</str>
<str name="description">Dscription</str>
<str name="slash-comments">23</str>
<str name="link">http://rss.slashdot.org/~r/Slashdot/slashdot/~3/dMLqmWSFcHE/story01.htm</str>
<str name="slash-department">but-it's-only-wafer-thin-metadata</str>
<date name="date">2013-07-04T15:06:00Z</date>
<long name="_version_">1439733898774839296</long></doc>
```

So my problem is that i cant seem to get data out
Tried with this:

```
<?php
    $x = simplexml_load_file('select.xml');
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($x);
    echo $xml->xpath("result/doc/str[@name='author']")[0];
?>
```

Server gives me a error

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Which error do you get? And maybe you need to do this xpath: `$xml->xpath("/result/doc/str[@name='author']")[1]`

Comment: This is the following error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'

I have tried everything. Nothing seems to help. What have I missed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not valid syntax to have `[0]` when accessing the xpath method<sup>!</sup>. It is ambiguous as to what the `[0]` applies to.

*<sup>!</sup> As of PHP 5.4.0, [array dereferencing for function/methods](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) is available.*

Your xpath also looks wrong for the XML you have posted.

This works:

```
$result = $xml->xpath("/doc/str[@name='author']");
echo "Author: " . $result[0];
```

Output:

```
Author: timothy
```

If you have multiple tags then you need to loop or change your xpath. For example you can do:

```
$xmlstr = '<doc>
    <str name="author">timothy</str>
    <str name="author_s">timothy</str>
    <str name="title">French Gov\'t Runs Vast Electronic Spying Operation of Its Own</str>
    <arr name="category">
        <str>communications</str>
        <str>test2</str>
    </arr>
   </doc>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);

$result = $xml->xpath("/doc/arr[@name='category']");
foreach($result as $xmlelement){
    foreach($xmlelement->children() as $child){
        echo "Category: $child" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Category: communications
Category: test2
```

Comment: Well this gives me more errors then I started with.

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 5: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in

Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in

Comment: You still need this line: `simplexml_load_file('select.xml');`

Comment: I had that but I had a nother path indicator in my XML which was "result". Work Perfectly now. Thank you !

Comment: But what if Category has multiple values in array ? how can i get all the values ?

Comment: Updated the answer with how to get multiple `<str>` from the category tag. You should look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php as this is what XPath returns. This will be your API after calling xpath

Comment: But isint It possible so every category has its own attribute value ? 
( I want to create lists according to diffrent categorys) ?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$xml->xpath("result/doc/str[@name='author']")[0]
```

To:

```
$xml->xpath("result/doc/str[@name='author'][1]")
```

`[0]` is not correct to get the first occurence. In XPath the first occurence is `[1]`. Also related to your error the `[0]` should be inside the XPath and not at the end.